# how to export images into xlsx file from oracle database

Tags: plsql, oracle12c, xlsx, plsql-package

I need an help to export images from an Oracle table into xlsx file while calling a procedure, I'm able to export strings,date and numbers but I could not find a way to export images into xlsx file

seeking suggestions

I want to export table data including images into xlsx file

Comment: Images are, I presume, stored in a BLOB datatype column. If you just "export" it, you'd get something unreadable, so I guess you'd want to actually see an image in XLSX file. If that's so, no idea, I don't know how to do it. As if the "as_xlsx" third party package, never heard of it either - did you contact its author and ask for assistance?